# Laserscan tf to odom frame (RVIZ)

Tags: rviz, laserscan, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi at all out there,

have a problem with a point that is displayed in RVIZ, but seems not to exist in our data, because all filtering efforts fail.

We do the following steps:

1. A laserscanner subscriber delivers scan data
2. We transform the data in our odometry frame with the tf package
3. We throw away some points that are to far away for our calculation
4. We apply an algorithm on the remaining data. We tried different algorithms but the problem still remains.

The point lies on the odometry frame origin.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210155/laserscan-tf-to-odom-frame-(rviz)/) by [Karl_Auer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4779/karl_auer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the problem. I'm splitting my laserscan into left and right and somehow i had some points in both vectors. Now I checked the vectors against each other for duplicates and erased them - problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [Karl_Auer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4779/karl_auer/) with karma: 3 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0